# GCP Monitoring - Incident does not contain system labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I've created an alert policy via the GCP console.This policy sends incidents to a PubSub notification channel.

For example: a high CPU utilization policy for containers

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "displayName": "...",
  "documentation": {},
  "conditions": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "displayName": "Kubernetes Container - CPU usage time",
      "conditionThreshold": {
        "aggregations": [
          {
            "alignmentPeriod": "300s",
            "perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_RATE"
          }
        ],
        "comparison": "COMPARISON_GT",
        "duration": "0s",
        "filter": "metric.type=\"kubernetes.io/container/cpu/core_usage_time\" resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
        "thresholdValue": 0.04,
        "trigger": {
          "count": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "alertStrategy": {
    "autoClose": "604800s",
    "notificationPrompts": [
      "OPENED"
    ]
  },
  "combiner": "OR",
  "enabled": true,
  "notificationChannels": [
    "..."
  ],
  "creationRecord": {
    "mutateTime": "...",
    "mutatedBy": "..."
  },
  "mutationRecord": {
    "mutateTime": "...",
    "mutatedBy": "..."
  }
}
```

Once I trigger this alert, and get the incident on the PubSub side, the metadata field for `system_labels` is always empty:

```json
    "metadata": {
      "system_labels": {},
      "user_labels": {}
    },
```

Even though, if I use the metrics explorer to view this resource I see that these labels are populated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would like to know more about the way you created the policy. Can you share the Query used to create the policy? In Addition to that, you're having problems in Cloud Monitoring also, or only to see the metadata in Cloud Pub/Sub?

Comment: The policy was created using the UI, nothing fancy. I've exported it to json and added to the original question above. As for your 2nd question, it's an issue with cloud monitoring not pubsub. I'm sending the same incident to other channels and getting the same issue.

Comment: Did you create a notification channel and authorize a Service account? Authorization lets the notifications service account publish each Pub/Sub topic that you are using as a notification channel.

Comment: I think you are not following. I am getting notifications on the channel - those notifications (incidents) are missing the metadata fields I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. Values for metadata.* variables are available only if the labels are explicitly included in a condition's filter or grouping for cross-series aggregation. That is, you must refer to the metadata label in either filter or grouping for it to have a value for the template. For more information refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#null-values).

Answer (score 0):

According with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) when you create a channel, you need to:

- Enable the Pub/Sub API and create a topic.
- Configure the notification channel for a topic.
- Authorize a service account.
- Set the notification channel in an alerting policy.

To use a Pub/Sub notification channel in an alerting policy, select Pub/Sub as the channel type, and then select the topic.
By default, the alerting backend attempts to generate a JSON packet with version 1.2 formatting.

By default the metadata field needs to have the following values:

```
"metadata": {
  "system_labels": { "labelkey": "labelvalue" },
  "user_labels": { "labelkey": "labelvalue" }
},
```

If the **“system_labels”** field does not present the “labelkey" and “labelvalue”, you need to review your configuration with the service account and be sure that you set the notification channel in the alerting policy correctly.

Please review the [examples of JSON packet and the schema](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels).

In the same article you will find detailed instructions about [Create a Channel on demand](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#on-demand) and [editing or deleting channels.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#edit-delete-channel)

---

You will need to enable a filter in your policy, in order to see the fields under `“metadata”:{` populated (whatever field you want to).

In order to confirm that, I replicated your scenario in Google Cloud. I created an alert and configured pub/Sub as one of the notification channels.

And, I proceeded to stress the VM to trigger the alerts. When I used a filter in the policy (In this case, the “system_labels=name”), the “metadata” field in the message’s topic in Pub/Sub showed me:

```
"metadata": {
      "system_labels": {"name": "pubsubtest-1"},
      "user_labels": {}
    },
```

But when I did not configure, the filter in the policy showed me:

```
"metadata": {
      "system_labels": {},
      "user_labels": {}
    },
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question - I do get notifications on the PubSub channel, which means I've setup everything correctly. I'm only missing the metadata fields. Is there some part in the configuration which is relevant only for these fields?

Comment: I added more information to my answer, i hope that this information could help you with your doubt.

Comment: First off thank you so much for your help! but what you suggests is a workaround for a bug. I don't want to set a filter on a field in order to get it's value, that's just bizarre. I also don't know the values of the field - that's why I need it in the first place. It should be present regardless - the same way resource labels appear without needing to set any filter.

Comment: @Omricoco, It's not a bug. Values for metadata.* variables are available only if the labels are explicitly included in a condition's filter or grouping for cross-series aggregation. That is, you must refer to the metadata label in either filter or grouping for it to have a value for the template. For more information refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables#null-values).

Comment: @ChandraKiranPasumarti That is what i was looking for! thank you. Feel free to add this is an answer and I will accept it.